# What's wrong with this proof that irreps over $\mathbb{C}$ are dimension $1$?

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Let $V$ be an irreducible representation of a finite group $G$ over the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$.

Then $[V, V]_{\mathbb{C}[G]} \cong \mathbb{C}$ since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed. It follows that $\mathbb{C}[G]$ acts on $V$ by scalars, so that all $\mathbb{C}$-subspaces of $V$ are $G$-invariant. Therefore $V$ must have only $2$ subspaces as a $k$-vector space, so that it must be $1$-dimensional.

On the other hand, $S_3$ has an irreducible $2$ dimensional representation, $\mathbb{C}^2$, which occurs as a sub representation of the canonical representation of $S_3$ on $\mathbb{C}^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd say "it follows $\mathbb C[G]$ acts on $V$ by scalars."

Taking your example of $\mathbb C[S_3]$, you know it is a noncommutative semisimple ring, and you are aware that $M_2(\mathbb C)$ appears in its factoriation. The way $\mathbb C[S_3]$ acts on the simple submodule for that piece is not via a scalar, but via $M_2(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: Say $V \cong \mathbb{C}^2$ is the irrep of $S_3$. $\mu_g : \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$, $v \mapsto g v$ has an eigenvalue, $\lambda I$. $\mu_g - \lambda I$ is a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module map between simple $\mathbb{C}[G]$ modules, and has proper image, so must be $0$. So $\mu_g = \lambda I$, so $\mu_g$ must be multiplication by a scalar. Since this works for each $g \in G$, all $g$ act by scalars on $V$, so all $\mathbb{C}$-subspaces of $V$ are $G$-invariant. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: @DeanYoung I don't think you have any way of ensuring $\mu_g$ is $\mathbb C[G]$ linear, it's only $\mathbb C$ linear in general.  In general, given a left $R$ module $M$, the map $v\mapsto rv$ is not $R$ linear on the left.  If $g$ were central you'd be OK but the issue is that it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @rschweib oh, I get it! Thanks so much! That's only if it's abelian.